# newenvironment: ERROR missing a number and Illegal number of measure

Tags: environments

I try to make a template for my assignment with \newenvironment. Somehow it yields the Error:

- Missing number, treated as zero.
- Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted)

Everytime i want to \begin{env_name}.

My Code for the new environment looks like this in the moment

```
\newenvironment{thm}[1]
{
\noindent
\textbf{\color{MidnightBlue}{Theorem} }
\labelsep {\textbf{\color{MidnightBlue}{#1}}}
\\
\itshape
}
{
\vspace * {20 pt}
}
```

and i call it in this way:

```
\begin{thm}{3.2}
Theorem
\end{thm}
```

These are my used packages:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} 
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb}

\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\usepackage{cmbright}
\usepackage[OT1]{fontenc}

\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}}
\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}
```

I looked in the internet and also at similar question here, but i couldn't find a solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is your use of `\labelsep`, which is a length (or dimension). When using that in code as-is, it is expected to be followed by another dimension used to update it. For example,

```
\labelsep 10pt
```

would update `\labelsep` to be `10pt` (an optional `=` is allowed: `\labelsep=10pt`). Since you didn't supply a dimension/length afterwards, TeX complains that you're missing a number and/or unit of measure.

Crudely, I imagine you want something like this as your definition for `thm`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\newenvironment{thm}[1]{%
  \par\addvspace{0.5\baselineskip}
  \noindent
  {\color{MidnightBlue}\bfseries Theorem~#1}%
  \par\nobreak
  \noindent\itshape\ignorespaces
}{%
  \par\addvspace{0.5\baselineskip}
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{thm}{3.2}
\lipsum[2]
\end{thm}

\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

If you're hard-coding theorem numbers in this way, one could only assume that you're specifically referring to ones that come from a different source. If you're creating these theorems and they need to be numbered sequentially, use the functionality provided by [`amsthm`](//ctan.org/pkg/amsthm) (that you're loading already).

Comment: Thank you so much, that solved my problem